# Как заставить перемапить данные внутри компонента Vue?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Всем привет!

Допустим я получаю такой массив с сервера:
`const persons = [{ name: 'Вася', job: 'Менеджер', age: 45 }, { name: 'Петя', job: 'Логист', age: 40 }`

Далее я делаю v-for данного массива и передаю пропсом каждый элемент внутрь компонента
`<person v-for="person in persons" :key="person.name" :person="person"/>`

Далее внутри компонента в хуке created я делаю маппинг для person, для того чтобы потом уже смапенные, красивые данные вставить в разметку, то есть в created делаю что-то типо:

`this.mappedPerson = person.map((item) => { ...item, name: 'Прекрасная должность + person.job', age: 'Прекрасный возраст + person.job', }`

Ну и далее эти данные вставляю в разметку. Все вроде ок. Я получил сырые данные в компонент, при создании компонента смаппил эти данные в нужный себе формат и вывел пользователю.

А далее я беру и редактирую данные своего person, отправляю запрос на сервер, сервер мне возвращает обновленный объект person, я его в store с помощью commit добавляю в список person, но в компоненте ничего не происходит! Я жду, что так как данные person изменились, произойдет перерендер компонента, в который я передаю этот person, соответственно в моем компоненте person снова вызовется маппинг данных. Но компонент  не перерендеривается, created не срабатывает.

Как в таких ситуациях заставить весь компонент заново смаппить переданные ему пропсы?

Comment: Потому что компонент не перерендеривается каждый раз, это дорогая операция для dom. Для таких целей используйте `watch()`

Comment: @VladimirGonchar так а разве атрибут :key в данной ситуации не должен отслеживать изменения итерируемого person и вызывать перерендер? вроде :key для этого и нужен, чтобы был уникальный ключ для элемента и при изменении этого элемента вызвать перерендер. или может я что-то не так понял

Comment: created выполняется только один раз. Сделайте в methods функцию mappedPerson(item) { return { ...item, name: 'Прекрасная должность + person.job', age: 'Прекрасный возраст + person.job', }; } и используйте её в разметке.

Comment: @ВикторКарев вы наверно имели ввиду computed, но суть ясна. Сделать вычисляемое свойство. Но мне кажется это забивает память приложения, так как при большом списке данных будет создаваться много лишних связей и зависимостей, чтобы отслеживать состояние полей. Тем более, что они могут вообще не обновиться, так как редактирование это лишь опция и не всегда используется.

Comment: Интересно, что в таком случае будет более производительно
1) Все поля, которые выводятся пользователю и могут быть обновлены/отредактированы, выводить через computed, чтобы изменения полей подхватывались на ходу
2) Завести глобальный watcher и через deep следить за всем объектом person и в случае отработки вотчера, вызвать функцию которая заново перемапит поля для вывода

Кто что думает?

Comment: Нет, я имел в виду именно methods. То есть использовать функцию с параметром.